# why is my vertex shader returning "error C5145: must write to gl_Position" and how can I fix it

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have been following the tutorials over at learnopengl.com, im on the section of shaders and I seem to have stumbled into a problem. when I run the project the console reads

```
ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED
Vertex info
-----------
(0) : error C5145: must write to gl_Position
```

I first tried looking to see if I had messed anything up, but everything looked fine to me.
then I copied all the code from the GitHub repository for that section and I still got the same error.

this is my vertex shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;

out vec3 ourColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
}
```

this is my fragment shader

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(ourColor, 1.0f);
}
```

this is the header file that compiles the shaders

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <glad/glad.h>

class Shader
{
public:
    GLuint Program;
    // Constructor generates the shader on the fly
    Shader(const GLchar* vertexPath, const GLchar* fragmentPath)
    {
        // 1. Retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fShaderFile;
        // ensures ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
        vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
        fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
        try
        {
            // Open files
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
            // Read file's buffer contents into streams
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
            // close file handlers
            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();
            // Convert stream into string
            vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
        }
        const GLchar* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const GLchar* fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
        // 2. Compile shaders
        GLuint vertex, fragment;
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[512];
        // Vertex Shader
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        // Print compile errors if any
        glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
        // Fragment Shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        // Print compile errors if any
        glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
        // Shader Program
        this->Program = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(this->Program, vertex);
        glAttachShader(this->Program, fragment);
        glLinkProgram(this->Program);
        // Print linking errors if any
        glGetProgramiv(this->Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(this->Program, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
        // Delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);

    }
    // Uses the current shader
    void Use()
    {
        glUseProgram(this->Program);
    }
};

#endif
```

what is causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  Or at least show the code that compiles and links the shader program.

Comment: I added the header file to the question

Comment: Did you accidentally swap the vertex and fragment shader source code when you construct the `Shader` object?

Comment: I just realized that they were swapped but after fixing them I still get the same error

Comment: @Realuther Most likely the filepaths are incorrect and the files are not read. Change `vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);` to `vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);`